# search a string in all the .log files in a directory using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to read all the .log files for todays file timestamp (i.e today's date yyyymmdd) in a folder which contains a string "scp error". And if condition satisfies move the name of .log file without extension to a new .txt file "redrop_files.txt"

this is what I have tried so far

```
Get-Item File*.log | ForEach-Object {
    $fil = $_.Name;
    
    foreach ($line in Get-Content $fil) {
        if ($line -eq "scp error") {
            $stat = "FAILED"
        }
    }

    if ($stat -eq "FAILED") {
        $errorfile = Get-ChildItem *.log | Rename-Item -NewName { $fil -replace '.log','' }
        Add-Content -Path .\redrop_files.txt "`n" $errorfile
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "it is wrong". Also, I don't see in your script where you would set the variable `f`.

Comment: folks have assumed this was a [tag:shell] question due to the tag yet your code is PowerShell. This has probably caused the downvotes of your question. Are you looking for a PowerShell answer or Shell?

Comment: also your code looks fair, there are a few issues with it, i.e.: `$stat` should be reset on each loop iteration and `break` once inside that condition. Also it's not clear what the `Rename-Item` is for.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon rename-item is for removing the extension .log from the file name.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon but I got no idea on how to tweak this script to run only for that .log file which is created on current date

Comment: But do you want to rename the file? That's not really clear in your question. I assume what you're looking to do by looking at your code is to append the file's Name (without extension) to the file `redrop_files.txt`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Exactly! I want to append all the files names of todays date without extension to a new file redrop_files.txt

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon And yes I don't want to rename the file

Comment: But don't really want to rename them correct? Because currently you're actually renaming the files

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon does this "rename-item" rename the original file name as well? As I don't want to do that. That's why I'm storing that new name to a "errorfile"

Answer (score 1):

You have one main problem: you don't store the results of `grep` anywhere so variable `f` is undefined.

It is not clear why you use `-n` with grep if you only want the filename; `-l` seems to make more sense.

So:

```
grep --include=\*.log -rlw '/path/' -e "scp error" |\
while read -r f; do
    echo "${f%%.*}"  
done > redrop_files.txt
```

Comment: This code assumes the logs don't contain newline in their filename (the `read` loads a line of `grep` output at a time and assumes each line contains precisely one filename)

Comment: Hi, I want to add the name of all the files excluding extension to the .txt file which contains the "scp error" string on a new line

Comment: If your version of `grep` has a `--null` (or sometimes `-Z`) option to use null bytes as a delimiter, you can solve the newline problem by adding that, then using `while IFS= read -r -d '' f` to read the filenames in the null-delimited format.

Comment: @GordonDavisson using null-delimited I/O is definitely a useful technique to know about. The requested output was line-oriented, so I just left the caveat

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
path=.
while read file; do
  echo ${file%%:*} >> redrop_files.txt
done < <(grep --include=\*.log -rnw $path -e "scp error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some minor mistakes, and a few improvements you could use, for example using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) to read the files. The biggest problem is that you're actually renaming the files, [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.2) actually renames files. What you want to do instead is append the `.BaseName` property (the file name without its extension) to your `redrop_files.txt` file.

```
Get-Item File*.log | ForEach-Object {
    # if this file is not from Today
    if($_.CreationTime -lt [datetime]::Today) {
        # skip it
        return
    }

    $append = switch -Wildcard -File $_.FullName {
        # if the line contains "scp error"
        '*scp error*' {
            # output true
            $true
            # and break this loop, no need to keep checking
            break
        }
    }

    # if the result of the switch loop was true
    if ($append) {
        # append to redrop_files.txt the .BaseName of this file
        Add-Content -Value $_.BaseName -Path .\redrop_files.txt
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but it doesn't take into account that only files we have to search for "scp errors" should be todays date file only\

Comment: @cheragdubey now it does, see the update

Comment: Let me try it first. I'll surely do once it works